# Error when using the Automatic Test Generation with Rational Rhapsody

Tags: visual-studio, atg, rhapsody, ibm-rational

I´m using Rational Rhapsody 8.3.1 and I tried to follow the ATG Tutorial, but when I press "Apply ATG" there's the following Error Message:

> ERROR: ATG is not applicable on configuration TPkg_TheTestCalc::TPkg_TheTestCalc_Comp::DefaultConfig.
>   Please check Environment settings.

In the Environment Settings "MSVC" and "Debug" is selected (Code Generation with Visual Studio works). I tried it with different Versions of RR and different Versions of Visual Studio, but always the same issue.

Does anyone know this Problem or what to try next?

Comment: Are you by any chance using Rhapsody in C? ATG only works with C++.

Comment: I am facing the exact same issue. Any solution ?